# I use CocoaPods set ReactiveCocoa with a few hours, but it does not work

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I try many times to set ReactiveCocoa with CocoaPods. It does not work. I don't know why. If you set the last version ReactiveCocoa 3.0 with CocoaPods successful, write the  bash commands.

Warning is "[!] Unable to find the Xcode project `/Users/calm/Downloads/ReactivePlayground-Starter/RWReactivePlayground/path/to/RWReactivePlayground.xcodproj.xcodeproj` for the target `Pods`."

How I fix it?

Comment: For starters, `RWReactivePlayground.xcodproj.xcodeproj` looks wrong.

Comment: Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find the Xcode project `/Users/calm/Downloads/ReactivePlayground-Starter/RWReactivePlayground/RWReactivePlayground.xcodeproj` for the target `Pods`.
I edit it and it show the warning again.

Comment: I am not set the RWReactivePlayground.xcodeproj and the Podfile in the  same directory. I think it's the reason.  Now it now show the warning .

Comment: I got it. I am not set the RWReactivePlayground.xcodeproj and the Podfile in the same directory.